# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' - Anaconda also crashing on launch

Tags: python3, pip, anaconda

I was trying to install cx_Oracle earlier today and in doing so, I somehow messed something up and now I am having this error whenever I try to run anything with pip including pip list. Pip3 list still works fine for some reason.

Anyway, the bigger issue is that my Anaconda Navigator application is now crashing when I try to click on the icon (Mac).

When I do pip3 list I get the below versions for the 2 programs which I read cause the issue:
pyOpenSSL = 22.0.0
cryptography = 38.0.1

Both of these are updated to the latest version (at least in pip3) which should resolve the issue. I am not sure if anaconda is referencing pip or pip3 though. If it is pip, I am unable to see the versions as I am getting the below error

```
> ....   File
> "/Users/nlcir/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py",
> line 1573, in X509StoreFlags
>     CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

Edit: I was able to go into the crypto.py file and remove the line and Anaconda is running again..

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509\_V\_FLAG\_CB\_ISSUER\_CHECK'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428181/module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I faced the same issue and was able to solve it based on your edit.
Edit: I was able to go into the crypto.py file and remove the line and Anaconda is running again..

Once in, I was able to upgrade PyOpenSSL from 19.0.0 to 22.0.0 from within Anaconda to update the pip.